# find all pieces matching regex

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying find all pieces in a txt-file that match this expression: p[0-9] or p[0-9][0-9].  I only want to print out the p and the number. This can be in a string like this: 123p3 but also something like this -p3. So I want to have as result two times p3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <textfile grep -P 'p[0-9]{1,2}' #add -o to only print matches
```